# A riddle of a reaper

Tags: riddle, history

I hope this riddle isn't too easy:

> Some see me as the reaper,
>
> > But am I not somehow?
>
> I was a patron,
>
> > Through time they celebrated me.
>
> They were going to cut me open,
>
> > To free what was inside of me.
>
> Eventually I was confined,
>
> > In a place of torment, I rest.
>
> Don't be confused,
>
> > As many confuse me with someone else.

Can you find out and explain what or who I am?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Chronos, titan of time, and Kronos, titan of agriclture
>  Added by OP: Cronus

Some see me as the reaper,
But am I not somehow?

> Some people mix up Chronos with Kronos, the titan of agriculture.
> Added by OP:  the identification of Cronus and Chronos gave rise to "Father Time" wielding the harvesting scythe

I was a patron,
Through time they celebrated me.

> A fesival for Chronos/Kronos?
> Added by OP: Cronus continued to preside as a patron of harvest

They were going to cut me open,
To free what was inside of me.

> Zeus cut Kronos up with his own scythe and released his siblings, who had been swallowed

Eventually I was confined,
In a place of torment, I rest.

> So he went to Tartarus

Don't be confused,
As many confuse me with someone else.

> Don't confuse Kronos/Chronos

Comment: Nice answer.  +1  The cutting was done to free his siblings too wasn't it?

Comment: Correct I edited some answers to make it all fit :)  & @BrentHackers correct :) Metis gave Cronus an emetic to force him to disgorge the children, or Zeus cut Cronus's stomach open.